# TypeError: Cannot read property 'easeTo' of undefined in ReactJS Mapbox-GL

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mapbox-gl-js

I'm building a ReactJS Mapbox project with `MapBox GL JS`.

My code demo below:

```
const Map = () => {
  var map;
  const [testState, setTestState] = useState(1);

  const testApp = () => {
    console.log(typeof map);
    setTestState(2); // set state
    map.easeTo({
      ....//some code
    })
  }

  useEffect(() =>{
    map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: "mapContainer",
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9",
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 12,
    });
  },[]) //I tried remove [] here
}
    .....// render
<button onClick={() => testApp()/>

export default Map;
```

When I run `onClick={() => testApp()}` on the first time everything's be OK. But in second time. I got:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'easeTo' of undefined
```

and the `undefined` in `console.log(typeof map)`
.

I tried remove `[]` on `useEffect`, the `map.easeTo` worked but the map will reload when I run `testApp()` (Why????).

I want each time when I click `button` the Map do not reload and function `testApp()` will run with my code above.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66271302/reactjs-mapbox-gl-invalid-type-container-must-be-a-string-or-htmlelement/66272085#66272085 solution's given here will work.

Answer (score 1):

So let's go through this step by step.

> I tried remove [] on useEffect, the map.easeTo worked but the map will reload when I run testApp() (Why????).

By removing `[]` from the `useEffect` hook, the code inside the hook will run on every component render. That's why the map reloads, because every render you create new instance of the `mapboxgl.Map` class.

I suggest you take a look at the [useEffect docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and compare the difference without the dependency array, with an empty dep array (`[]`) or with actual dependencies.

> When I run onClick={() => testApp()} on the first time everything's be OK. But in second time. I got: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'easeTo' of undefined

Whenever you see this type of error "Cannot read property X of undefined", it means that you called a method on an object that is `undefined`. In this case, during the second render, the `var map;` is `undefined`.

In React's functional component, you have to use either `useState` or `useRef` to persists the state between renders.

The component is function after all, so every time it gets called, new context is created and the variables are undefined.

Lastly, you can instantiate the `mapboxgl.Map` outside of the component, in the file context, if you expect the use the same map during the whole runtime of your app. Like so:

```js
const MAP_INSTANCE = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: "mapContainer",
    style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9",
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 12,
  });

const Map = () => {
    const [testState, setTestState] = useState(1);
  
    const testApp = () => {
      console.log(typeof map);
      setTestState(2); // set state
      MAP_INSTANCE.easeTo({
        // Some code
      })
    } 
    return <button onClick={() => testApp()} />
};
  
export default Map;
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. I have tried it before. But I got `Container 'mapContainer' not found.` notice