# ReactJS Mapbox-gl Invalid type: 'container' must be a String or HTMLElement

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mapbox-gl-js

I'm building a small App using ReactJS and Mapbox GL JS.

```
const MapRender = () => {
  const mapContainerRef = useRef(null);
  const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: mapContainerRef.current,
    style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 1
  });
  map();

  useEffect(()=>{
  ..........//Code 
  },[]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="map-container" ref={mapContainerRef} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MapRender;
```

My code above basiclly display a map on a webpage. But I got the error messenge:

```
Invalid type: 'container' must be a String or HTMLElement.
```

Everythings will be fine if I put `const map = new mapboxgl.Map()` into `useEffect()` but it's mean eachtime when I `setState` the Map will call and reload again.

I expect the use the same map during the whole runtime of my app.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Could you try `const mapContainerRef = useRef();`?

Comment: I tried but it not work. The same  error messenge.

Comment: So the issue is you do not want the map to be recreated every single time? Cause when you `setState` it is expected that the map will rerender in order to show the new data.

Comment: In my project, some State only for `UI/UX` , not for the map. So I don't want the map recall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want the map to be reinitialized again every single time there is new data being passed to it. You can do the following where, the map is created when the ref is connected to the container div and it will not create the map if it's already been created.

```
export default function MapRender() {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current && !map) {
      const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: ref.current,
        style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 1
      });
      setMap(map);
    }
  }, [ref, map]);
  return <div className="map-container" ref={ref} />;
}
```

Comment: excuse me, what's `onInit` ? 
I got `onInit is not defined`.

Comment: @Alex sorry that's not needed I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Use below format to remove TS Error:

```
const content = useRef<string | HTMLElement>(null);
```

Code where Mapbox gl Map Instance will be created once:

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xnetjp?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/App.js

This is the TS Error as in mapbox-gl.d.ts(Declaration File) says that the container has to be a string or an HTML element.

Screenshot:

[image]

Learning [References](https://linguinecode.com/post/how-to-use-react-useref-with-typescript)

Thanks!